# How to avoid error 404 webpage notfound with VITE REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

I am trying to make a VITE project instead of Create react app but when I run, I got "404 error".

I have open a terminal and then enter this command :

- npm create vite@latest client (using react - javascript)
- cd client
- npm i
- npm run dev

After running, this is the response :

```
  VITE v4.3.9  ready in 956 ms

  ➜  Local:   http://127.0.0.1:5173/
  ➜  Network: use --host to expose
  ➜  press h to show help
```

But now, when I open http://127.0.0.1:5173/ , I got a 404 error

*This 127.0.0.1 page can’t be foundNo webpage was found for the web address: http://127.0.0.1:5173/*

What i have already tried :

Config the vite.config.js with another port number

```
  import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
    import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
    
        // https://vitejs.dev/config/
        export default defineConfig({
          plugins: [react()],
         server: {
            port: 3000,
          }
        })
```

Edit the scripts in package.json.

```
 "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite --port 5173",
      },
```

Change the place of index.html to public and src just to try.
This is my initial code structure :
[image]

To know :

I have react 18.2.
node 16.15.0.
vite 4.3.9.
Create react app project is working and running, only vite is not

Answer (score 0):

just adding --host fixed this for me.

so like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "vite --host"
}
```

Comment: Still got This localhost page can’t be found with this change in package.json